# How to run multiple input files one after another in C-program

Tags: c, file, input

I have a C-Program, which need to be run for 10 different input files. Instead of running the program 10 different times, is it possible to run just 1 time allowing to run each file one after another.

Thank you.
Regards,
Kamal

Comment: Put the file-handling logic into a separate function, call that function for every file?

Answer (score 4):

Of course, that's what the `main` arguments are for:

```
void process_file(char const * filename);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        process_file(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
./a.out file1 file2 file3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

`argc` is argument count, so when you pass arguments to your program this variable will tell your main how many arguments have been passed.

`argv[0]` -> your program's name

`argv[1]..argv[n]` -> the name of the argumets passed.

So in your main:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
   fopen(argv[i],....);
}
```

And you can pass the arguments either in the project properties (if you are using MSVS), of command line.